# Output XML nodes by checking if all their successors elements nodes values are greater than a certain fixed value?

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I have the following document where I want to select all nodes with their associated IDs iff all their successor node elements are greater than 300.

```
<item>
    <deposit id="1">
        <amount>1200</amount>
        <amount>5000</amount>
        <amount>2300</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="2">
        <amount>300</amount>
        <amount>1500</amount>
        <amount>700</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="3">
        <amount>300</amount>
        <amount>500</amount>
        <amount>700</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="4">
        <amount>300</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="5">
        <amount>3500</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="6">
        <amount>1000</amount>
    </deposit>
</item>
```

I've tried to run the following XQuery chunk but it gave me same as the above document without any changes.

```
let $e := $depot/deposit
for $a in $e/amount
return if (data($a/preceding-sibling::amount)>"300") then $e else ()
```

I am expecting to have the following query result,

```
<item>
    <deposit id="1">
        <amount>1200</amount>
        <amount>5000</amount>
        <amount>2300</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="5">
        <amount>3500</amount>
    </deposit>
    <deposit id="6">
        <amount>1000</amount>
    </deposit>
</item>
```

Comment: You seem confused about XPath axes. By "successor elements" it seems you mean "child elements". And I can't see why you thought that preceding-sibling might be relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you to your desired output:

```
let $item := //deposit[not(amount[text()<=300])]

return 
(<item>
{$item}
</item>)
```

Comment: Or more succinctly, `<item>{//deposit[not(amount le 300)]}</item>`

Comment: @MichaelKay - OP was asking for for an xquery expression, not just xpath, but - yes - less can definitely be more!

Comment: XPath is a subset of XQuery, so an XPath solution is also an XQuery solution. But actually, the wrapper `<item>` element means that my solution isn't pure XPath either. The notion that an XQuery solution has to be a FLWOR expression is one I try hard to dispel.